# sqlQuery: impossible to get the ID number as Character into R?

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, rodbc

I'm using the `RODBC` package inside an ORACLE DATA BASE (DB). Everything is doing very well, but I need to obtain a table from this DB and some variables as character type, not numbers.

So, I made my query like this:

```
e    ManzResul_VIII<-sqlQuery(con,"select distinct t.fono_id_dis,
            t.id_predio,
            t.co_calle,
            t.nu_casa,
            t.x,
            t.y,
            t.plancheta  from c_araya.proy_dist08_todo t  where nvl(t.fono_tipo_dis, '-') not in ('CLIENTE', 'POTENCIAL', 'CARTERA')  and nvl(t.x, 0) <> 0 ")
```

Is impossible to get the ID number as Character, this query change the type of my iDs variables from Character to Numeric type (The ID has a zero at the beginning, but has been changed it into a number). I have read the function description, but I can see how to manage it.

Any idea would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the select statement work as expected outside of R? If it does not then mplourde's answer should work. If it does then try `sqlQuery(con,"select ...",as.is=T)`

Answer (score 2):

Change the query to cast the id to the data type you want:

```
select distinct cast(t.fono_id_dis as varchar(255)) as id
. . .
```

This should work with most databases.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
library(RODBC)
con <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=[your server name];database=[your database name];trusted_connection=true')
ManzResul_VIII<-sqlQuery(con,"select distinct ('m' + id) as id from [your table]")
```