# what to do NOT to round my keyid while importing table from oracle to R

Tags: r, key, unique, rounding

I have a table in oracle server like that (keyid with 20 digits)

[image]

when I import this table with odbc package it ROUNDS the key ids.

df <- sqlQuery(dwh, "select keyid from mytable")

(I already use options(scipen=999) not to show as e)

How can I get this keyid as text or sometihng else not to round the keyid?

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823298/sqlquery-impossible-to-get-the-id-number-as-character-into-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlQuery: impossible to get the ID number as Character into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823298/sqlquery-impossible-to-get-the-id-number-as-character-into-r)

Comment: did not work sorry...